# JetBrains PhpStorm - Synchronize with FTP server

Tags: ftp, synchronization, phpstorm

When I create a new project from existing files, in my case FTP, the application downloads the files and uploads my changes. But I miss the option which looks whether the files ON THE SERVER changed and synchronzizes it or notifies me.

Is there any option like this? I mean it's really necessary, for example when my colleague works on my project on the server with another tool like Notepad++. In this case when I would open PhpStorm, it overwrites the newer file on the server with the old without checking.

Comment: This is what version control systems are for.

Comment: *"it overwrites the newer file on the server with the old without checking."* -- PhpStorm has an option just for that -- `Warn when uploading over new file` under `Settings | Deployment | Options` (plus another one just below it). But automatically detecting/downloading remote changes to local computer -- No. You can also use "Sync" instead of just "Upload" -- in this case you will see a Diff screen before actual uploading starts

Answer (score 0):

That option does not exist yet, but there is a running issue on Jetbrains, might want to check it out:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1284